# React dev tools - Deactivate "break on warnings"

Tags: reactjs, javascript-debugger

While developing with create-react-app, my browser enters debugger mode on warnings:

[image: Paused in debugger]

It breaks on the source code of react-dev-tools:

```js
   // --- Welcome to debugging with React DevTools ---
   // This debugger statement means that you've enabled the "break on warnings" feature.
   // Use the browser's Call Stack panel to step out of this override function-
   // to where the original warning or error was logged.
```

How can I deactivate this behavior?

Comment: This behavior is totally annoying. I really would like to know how to disable it

Comment: here is a step by step instruction by Dan https://github.com/facebook/react/issues/19308#issuecomment-656682924 to remove this behavior for now

Comment: My solution was to blackbox that particular file so the debugger skips it entirely. Unless you're developing that plugin you should be good to do that.

Answer (score 86, accepted):

Go to Chrome Devtools → in the Chrome console, go to *Component* → Click on *Settings* → unset *Break on Warning*. Do the same in *Profiler* → *Settings* → unset *Break on warning*.

@cadoman pointed check and then uncheck to make work for sure.

P.S: Image from https://github.com/facebook/react/issues/19308#issuecomment-656669792

[image]

Comment: And you need to check then uncheck if it is not already checked

Comment: There also seems to be a bug where the checkbox is getting confused between the Profiler and the Component settings.  Check or uncheck on one, then the other shows the last value.  So as cadoman said, just check and uncheck.

Comment: haaa, I found you :)

Answer (score 16):

Based on pull request *[DevTools: Make break-on-warn off by default #19309](https://github.com/facebook/react/pull/19309)* it seems it's a bug.

The Break On Warnings box was unchecked for me and it still would break. Removing and readding the extension to force an update fixed it for me.

I don't know of another way to force Chrome to update an extension outside of its regular schedule.

Answer (score 5):

Go to your ReactDev tools in the tab Debugging and disable "Break on Warning".

I think this new behavior started today with this new PR: https://github.com/facebook/react/pull/19048

Answer (score 4):

The issue is due to a recent release. A Workaround proposed by the React team is:

- Go to *Chrome Developer Tools*
- Click on the *Components* Tab (React Developer Tools Extension)
- Click on the *Settings* icon (located next to the component search box)
- Once modal opens select the *Debugging* tab
- Finally, double click on the *Break on Warnings* checkbox (check and unchecked)

Make sure at last the *Break on Warnings* checkbox is unchecked.

Reference: [Issue link](https://github.com/facebook/react/issues/19308#issuecomment-656669792)

[image]

Answer (score 3):

It's a known issue. A workaround is posted on GitHub: *[Bug: Unexpected debugger statement in DevTools (solved) #19308](https://github.com/facebook/react/issues/19308#issuecomment-656669792)*

Answer (score 3):

Chrome has a "BlackBox script" feature which is useful in this case.

1. Go to Chrome Developer tools -> source tab
2. Select "react_developer_tools.js" from the left pane
3. Right-click file and select "Blackbox script"

[image]